# catch violates the semantic approximation order?

Tags: haskell

The semantic approximation order states that if a function `f` is defined when one its arguments is not, then `f` is constant in that argument (it doesn't use it). But consider this function,

```
import Control.Exception

handleAll :: SomeException -> IO ()
handleAll e = putStrLn "caught"

f :: String -> IO ()
f x = catch (putStrLn x) handleAll
```

`f undefined` displays `caught` in GHCi, so it looks defined. However `f` is not constant in its argument, because `f "test"` displays `test`.

Is there a mistake somewhere ?

Comment: There's no mistake - this principle only applies to pure functions. (Note even that isn't true, due to `seq` and friends). You only see the difference because you are executing the `IO` action, which is 'technically' only possible in `main` - all other manipulation with `IO` just builds new terms, or, you cannot observe the value of a term of type `IO x`.

Comment: `seq` does not violate the principle being discussed here.

Comment: `catch` turns out to be really hard to get right. I've actually been working on fixing relevant GHC bugs over the past week or two.

Comment: @dfeuer I reckon there is a theoretical problem with `catch`. By Curry-Howard, bottom is associated to mathematical falsity. And False is a logical black hole : for any proposition `P`, False implies `P`. Once you've entered bottom you cannot get out, you're doomed to speaking nonsense, as happens in infinite loops. `catch` intends to convert a bottom back to a defined value, I cannot see how it can do it right.

Comment: By that reasoning does `f x = \y -> print (x, y)` not use x?

Comment: @immibis Indeed, `\_ -> undefined` is different from `undefined`. Still, what `catch` does above seems a lot more defined than `\_ -> undefined`, as it has no latent bottoms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To model exceptions and `catch` properly you need a richer denotational semantics for terms, that distinguishes exceptions from nontermination (and that distinguishes different exceptions from each other). See [A semantics for imprecise exceptions (pdf)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1999/05/except.pdf) for the semantics that GHC implements.

Note that this has no effect on the denotational semantics of the "pure fragment" of Haskell, since you have no way to observe distinctions between `IO a` values in pure code (aside from bottom vs. not-bottom).

To clarify what I mean by the "pure fragment" of Haskell, imagine defining the `IO` type as

```
data IO a = MkIO
```

and `catch` as

```
catch a h = MkIO
```

Now there's no problem with your `f`, since both `f undefined` and `f "test"` are equal to `MkIO`. From the viewpoint of denotational semantics this corresponds to the interpretation

> [[`IO t`]] = {⊥ < ⊤}

Since the only operations we can do with IO actions are `seq`ing them and combining them into other IO actions, it's a perfectly consistent denotational semantics which does not compromise your ability to talk about the semantics of things like `length :: [Bool] -> Integer`. It just happens to be useless for understanding what happens when you execute an IO action. But if you wanted to treat that in a denotational semantics, you'd encounter many difficulties besides exceptions.

Comment: If there was provably only one `IO a` as you wrote (only one constructor `MkIO` without parameters), the compiler would optimize `f`, forcing it to be constant, equal to this unique `IO a`. This is not what happens, as the execution in GHCi shows. I understand from the paper about imprecise exceptions that GHC distinguishes several kinds of bottoms : ones that can be caught, others, such as infinite loops, that can't. I wonder how that translates via Curry-Howard, bottom is associated to mathematical falsity and there's only one of it.

Comment: Sure, I explicitly said that this denotational semantics (with exceptions identified with nontermination, and IO treated as a singleton) does not help you predict what will happen when you execute an IO action.